# How to cast a ComboBox.SelectedItem() to int?

Tags: java, casting

I try to cast a ComboBox.SelectedItem() to int and it isn't working. I know that ComboBox.SelectedItem() has the type String and I casted it like this:

```
 int idprovider = ((Integer)IdProviderComboBox.getSelectedItem()).intValue();
```

but I get the error:
     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Maybe someone has an idea.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are casting String to Integer hence its throwing ClassCastException, to get int out of a String use one of the following:

Update:

JComboBox.getSelectedItem() will return you Object, to covert it to int use :

```
int idprovider = Integer.valueOf((String)IdProviderComboBox.getSelectedItem()); // Internally calls parseInt, returns Integer, Java converts it to int for you.

int idprovider = Integer.parseInt((String)IdProviderComboBox.getSelectedItem()); // Since you need int use this better
```

Comment: I tried your method @mprabhat, but I get this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Integer.valueOf

Comment: I tried also with parseInt and at the beginning of the row where the cast is written @mprabhat, it appears the error no suitable method found for parseInt(java.lang.Object). method java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) is not applicable - actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation convertion. And when I run the program, it appears the error java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Integer.parseInt